# Trying to get the date from the bootstrap datepicker to working right

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

Basically, the date that I choose does goto the textbox. But since it's not putting the date directly into the StartDateTextBox.Value, I can't access the date on the StartDateTextBox. Is there a way to fix this?

```
<script>
        $(function ()
        {
            $("#StartDateTextBox").datepicker({ showOn: "button", buttonImage: "./calendarFull.png", buttonImageOnly: true });

            document.getElementById('StartDateTextBox').value = $("StartDateTextBox").valueOf();
            var sdf = 234;
        }

        );
</script>
<script>
        $("StartDateTextBox").click(function (event) {
            alert($(this).attr("data-my-custom-data"));
            alert($(this).attr("data-row-id"));
            alert($(this).attr("href"));

            event.preventDefault(); // To avoid browsing to href...
        });
        document.getElementById('StartDateTextBox').value = " 234 ";
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please confirm you're using the Bootstrap datepicker from http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/.

Comment: In your sample, you reference `$("StartDateTextBox").valueOf()` and  `$("StartDateTextBox").click(function (event) {`, however `$("StartDateTextBox")` is missing a "#" or "." (to select by ID or class), otherwise jQuery won't select the element.

I'm also confused about what the sample is trying to achieve. Why is there a "href" attribute on a textbox? Can you please explain more clearly what you are doing and trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to attempt an answer before I get a reply to my comments on the question:

When I encounter a problem like this (and from your posted code I'm guessing you've been doing the try-and-see-what-happens approach to solving the problem), I like to go back to basics. I start with a fresh page that has only what I want on it: references to jQuery, Bootstrap, and the date-picker library, plus the bare minimum test UI and script.

Try this:
Add your text box t o the page: `<input type="text" value="" id="StartDateTextBox" />`, then the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#StartDateTextBox").datepicker({ showOn: "button", buttonImage: "./calendarFull.png", buttonImageOnly: true });
});
</script>
```

I've tested that code and know it works. It generates you pop-up date picker when you focus on the text box, and adds the date you select into the text box. 
And notice I've used `$(document).ready()`? That help ensure libraries have loaded first before we initialise the date-picker.

I see you're mixing both native Javascript selectors and jQuery. Pick one and stick with it to save yourself confusion in switching between styles. jQuery works well, so I suggest you use that.

Now, we want to access the selected date that is now in the textbox? Try this:

```
function ShowDateValue()
{
    alert($("#StartDateTextBox").val());
}
```

That should display the day from the textbox in an alert dialog.

What do you need to do next? I see you're referencing hrefs and talking about stopping browsing to links, so I suspect there is more to this problem. Step me through and I can help.